# Fetch all rows in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra table containing 3 million rows. Now I am trying to fetch all the rows and write them to several csv files. I know it is impossible to perform `select * from mytable`. Could someone please tell how I can do this?

Or are there any ways to read the rows `n` rows by `n` rows without specifying any `where` conditions?

Comment: Thanks. I am so glad to hear that it is possible to do this. May I know how? I know that I may need to rethink my data schema. But it is too late now, and it take about 3 months to recollect the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

as I know, one improvement in cassandra 2.0 *'on the driver side'* is automatic-paging. you can do something like this :

```
Statement stmt = new SimpleStatement("SELECT * FROM images LIMIT 3000000");
stmt.setFetchSize(100);
ResultSet rs = session.execute(stmt);

// Iterate over the ResultSet here
```

for more read [Improvements on the driver side with Cassandra 2.0](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0)

you can find the driver [here](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver).

Comment: Sounds like this can solve the problem. I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: poor performance, because of full cluster scan. But it can be used, just to dump data.

Comment: @ubombi I perfectly agree with you. Plus since the paging is done on the client side, records added while you are fetching the results are not retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Pig to read the data and store it into HDFS, then copy it out as a single file:

In Pig:

```
data = LOAD 'cql://your_ksp/your_table' USING CqlStorage();
STORE data INTO '/path/to/output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

From OS shell:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal hdfs://hadoop_url/path/to/output /path/to/local/storage
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Pig. But I will learn and try it for sure. Thanks.

Comment: Pig is probably the most commonly used mechanism for data loading and exploration in Cassandra.  It compiles to mapreduce and submits to Hadoop seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

by default with select statement you can get only 100000 records.. so after that if you have to retrieve records you have to specify limit..

`Select * from tablename LIMIT 10000000` (in your case 3 million then specify it)...

Comment: If you fetch too many rows at a time, you will get `rpc_timeout` error

Comment: increasing the read request timeout does not seem a good approach. With a proper data model in cassandra your application should now the cassanda partition keys and do select for each partition