# Cassandra back using java code

Tags: cassandra, backup

Is there a way that i can backup a single table in Apache Cassandra with java code. i want to run such code once every week using a scheduler. Can some one share links to such resources, if there any?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this answer.

[Fetch all rows in cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745322/fetch-all-rows-in-cassandra)

It's just a matter of adding code to export let's say every row to csv or some similar format that would be fine for you.

You will also have to write script to load this data, but those are just simple inserts.