# How to determine time stamps for Cassandra queries

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

One of The values inserted into the table  is **current time.**  I compute the current time using  `toTimestamp(now())`. Now, I want to compute current time minus 90 days , current time minus 15 days. 
My question is how do I compute `current time  -  nth day` ?

Query for current timestamp :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (col_1, col_2, col_3) VALUES ('val_1', toTimestamp(now()), val_3);
```

In the above query, val_2 is current timestamp. Current time stamp is determined by

```
toTimestamp(now())
```

How do I compute `current time - 90 days , current time - 2weeks`

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not built into CQL.

If you are able to use UDFs, you can (building on the example given here:
[How to get Last 6 Month data comparing with timestamp column using cassandra query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198775/how-to-get-last-6-month-data-comparing-with-timestamp-column-using-cassandra-que)) do the following:

Enable UDFs as needed by adding or changing this line to true in cassandra.yaml:

```
enable_user_defined_functions: true
```

Then add two [user defined functions](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/functions.html#user-defined-functions) like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dateadd(date timestamp, daydiff int)
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    RETURNS timestamp
    LANGUAGE java
    AS $$java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();c.setTime(date);c.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, daydiff);return c.getTime();$$

CREATE FUNCTION weekadd(date timestamp, weekdiff int)
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT
    RETURNS timestamp
    LANGUAGE java
    AS $$java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();c.setTime(date);c.add(java.util.Calendar.DATE, weekdiff*7);return c.getTime();$$
```

Select the data from your table like this:

```
select dateadd(col_2,-90) from TABLE_NAME;
select weekadd(col_2,-2) from TABLE_NAME;
```

Comment: @Valerir Parham-thompson, Thanks for the response. Where do I define the UDF ? I'm connecting to the DB via python using cassandra  driver and executing the cql. Should I add the UDF as part of my python script ?

Comment: You need to define udf as part of your schema in Cassandra..and while executing cql u need to use them.note that the language for logic of udf by default support Java . Check https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-user-defined-functions-python-driver