# Retrieve rows from last 24 hours

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have a table with the following (with other fields removed)

```
CREATE TABLE if NOT EXISTS request_audit (
   user_id text,
   request_body text,
   lookup_timestamp TIMESTAMP
   PRIMARY KEY ((user_id), lookup_timestamp)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( lookup_timestamp DESC);
```

I create a record with the following

`INSERT INTO request_audit (user_id, lookup_timestamp, request_body) VALUES (?, ?, toTimestamp(now()))`

I am trying to retrieve all rows within the last 24 hours, but I am having trouble with the timestamp, 
I have tried

`SELECT * from request_audit WHERE user_id = '1234' AND lookup_timestamp > toTimestamp(now() - "1 day" )`
and various other ways of trying to take a day away from the query.

Comment: Why don’t you add a date (without time) in the primary key? I think having different partitions in this case could be good, just to avoid hotspots in case one user gets a lot of rows (even if you already have a reverse time series). You then manage the last 24 hours with two queries (in parallel).

Answer (score 4):

Cassandra has a very limited date operation support. What you need is a custom function to do date math calculation.

Inspired from here.
[How to get Last 6 Month data comparing with timestamp column using cassandra query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43198775/how-to-get-last-6-month-data-comparing-with-timestamp-column-using-cassandra-que)

you can write a UDF (user defined function) to date operation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dateAdd(date timestamp, day int)     
CALLED ON NULL INPUT     
RETURNS timestamp     
LANGUAGE java     
AS 
$$java.util.Calendar c = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
c.add(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
return c.getTime();$$ ;
```

remember that you would have to enable UDF in config. Cassandra.yml. Hope that is possible.

```
enable_user_defined_functions: true
```

once done this query works perfectly.

```
SELECT * from request_audit WHERE user_id = '1234' AND lookup_timestamp > dateAdd(dateof(now()), -1)
```

Comment: Modern code for calculating 24 hours ago: `java.time.Instant.now().minus( 24 , ChronoUnit.HOURS )`. If you must have a legacy class `java.util.Date` object as the result, wrap that code in a call to `Date.from( … )`.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't do it directly from CQL, as it doesn't support this kind of expressions. If you're running this query from `cqlsh`, then you can try to substitute the desired date with something like this:

```sh
date --date='-1 day' '+%F %T%z'
```

and execute this query.

If you're invoking this from your program, just use corresponding date/time library to get date corresponding -1 day, but this depends on the language that you're using.