# Verify Cassandra data migration

Tags: java, spring-mvc, cassandra

I want to migrate some data from an existing database to Cassandra DB.
Post migration, I want to verify whether all the data were migrated successfully or not.
I was wondering whether Cassandra Driver for JAVA provides any internal implementation feature to verify the same so that I can reduce the unnecessary overhead incurred during the interaction with Cassandra DB?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the type of database that you are migrating from you can either check row per row in your previous database and then make queries against cassandra to see if the rows are there. That would be the safest approach imho.

Then you can do some very complex stuff like having spark jobs that do the comparisons.

Or you can iterate over all the rows in cassandra and check against the original database. Something like this: [Fetch all rows in cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745322/fetch-all-rows-in-cassandra)

The list could go on and on. For details you would have to tell more about the originating database, data model in cassandra and give some context what it means for a row to be verified ... other than it's there.