# count query in cassandra timeout on large data set

Tags: cassandra

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE star.star_event (
 eventnumber int,
 primarytracks int,
 prodtime double,
 antinucleus int,
 eventfile int,
 eventtime double,
 histfile bigint,
 multiplicity int,
 nabovelb int,
 nbelowlb int,
 nlb int,
 pt double,
 runnumber int,
 vertexx double,
 vertexy double,
 vertexz double,
 PRIMARY KEY (eventnumber, primarytracks, prodtime)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (primarytracks ASC, prodtime ASC)
```

I am trying to do `select count(1) from star_event`. I know it's a valid query supported in cassandra, at least for small amount of data. But with a huge dataset it seems to be not working.

constantly getting error

```
ReadTimeout: Error from server: code=1200 [Coordinator node timed out
waiting for replica nodes' responses] message="Operation timed out -
received  only 0 responses." info={'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

Increased the default `ReadTimeout` value in `cassandra.yaml` still no luck. What are the workarounds available.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you know your way around with cassandra enough ;) And that you already tried changing the yaml file. There isn't really much you can do around this one as it is now and by using cassandra only (other than maybe even further increase the timeout and see what happens)

Basically sometimes the data is just to big. So you have to work around this one. There are couple of ways to do this:

1. Performing the count by an outside process - spark always worked really nice for me, but I also coded some own tools to process the data very often. You might use this answer for your own count tool https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750872/7413631
2. Try to remodel the data - but this one is no good for you I guess since breaking the table into multiple smaller one doesn't seem optimal
3. Use the fuzzy cassandra approximation (within 128) if you are just interested into ball park by using table statistics `nodetool cfstats`: http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=24
4. Trying to employ counter columns, basically have one more update for every insert that you make that would actually increase counter value. But you would need also to set it to some initial value once you start counting.

It all depends, if this count is something you don't do often and can wait own script or spark is o.k. if you have to have it right away I would go with the counter columns.

Comment: Nice points very helpful . So if spark can be a substitute to this probs. I am not clear on this ,  if cassandra itself  not able to handle such queries then spark will be?

Comment: Spark will actually pull the rows out in smaller chunks and count them :) I know this might sound a bit weird I agree but this just doesn't perform well  in a single request if the amount of data is big so yes you also need something on the side. Distributed count is always a bit of a problem.

Comment: Interesting I will try this for sure and get back to you. Thanks for showing me the direction :)