# How to check all data were added in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra stress to test the performance of the cassandra DB. Seems that the performance of cassandra DB is awesome. But when I check how much data was inserted into cassandra with `select count(*) from table Name;`. I got a timeout error. Anyone knows how to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice intro to the subject:

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/counting-keys-in-cassandra

You can also check tis answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23750872/7413631

Basically when I'm doing my own stress testing with actual data I also have to write code that verifies the whole thing.

But when using stress test utility only it's sufficient to first call `write` and then `read` operation with the same count.